# What are the ways and steps to import data for Retrospective Boards?

Tags: csv, azure-devops, import, import-from-excel, workitem

I currently have Start, Stop, Continue stickie notes on Miro and want to have an automated way to transfer these items into the Start, Stop, Continue template for Azure DevOps Retrospectives. However, cards in Retrospectives are not work items and I can only find documentation to on how to import as work items, but cards in Retrospectives aren't considered work items. Thus, I would like to know if there is a way to import data (i.e. a csv file) to create retrospective cards in Azure DevOps Retrospectives, or even better, how to automatically transfer Miro stickies to become Retrospective cards.

I've already integrated Miro with Azure Dev Ops and just like how you can create work items in Miro to be reflected in Azure, I was expecting to be able to have the stickies in Miro reflect as Retrospective cards in Azure. However, I do not see a feature or documentation on how to have stickies from Miro be transformed into cards for Retrospectives.

I've tried going to Queries and importing .csv files, hoping to have them be created already as cards in Retrospectives, however it creates work items and I do not need them to be work items.

Under Retrospectives, I have also tried selecting 'Import Data', however nothing seems happen.